# KeyDown event not working. No errors however

Tags: c#, winforms

So I have KeyDown event that is not working correctly. The pacman appears on the map but does not respond to any key presses. There are no errors.

Here it is (Gameboard is name of the form, mapPictureBox the name of the picture box):

```
private void Gameboard_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
    {
        pacman.yPosition += 10;
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
    {
        pacman.yPosition -= 10;
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
    {
        pacman.xPosition -= 10;
    }
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
    {
        pacman.xPosition += 10;
    }
    mapPictureBox.Invalidate();
}
```

I have an instance of the MovingPacman class declared at the top(where I call images:

```
MovingPacman pacman = new MovingPacman();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: does it have keyboard focus?

Comment: Oh. I'll try and add that now.

Comment: Is it only the `Keys.Down` that is not working properly?

Comment: did you attach the event `Gameboard_KeyDown` ?

Comment: No none of the keys are working. And yes the event is attached.

Comment: The event isn't being triggered it seems. @Strobe: If you put a print statement in the `Gameboard_KeyDown` method, does it print?

Comment: Try to set your Form's KeyPreview property to true.

Comment: No, there does not appear to be anything printing. How do I go about ovveriding the ProcessCmdKey()?

Comment: Where did that guys comments go? Wonder why he deleted them.

Comment: I gave up on this question.  Everybody thinks that KeyPreview should work.  Sucks to be the only nay-sayer.  Good luck.

Comment: Nevermind I'm an idiot. Made a silly mistake on up in the code. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

Set the **KeyPreview** property of your form to True. By default, edit controls consume key events, this property enable the form to handle events before controls do.
Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171538%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Are you sure the form is the active windows of your app?

Comment: Yes? There is only the form and the picturebox which the pacman is drawn in. I don't see what the problem is. I have no problem adjusting the starting position of the pacman by changing the x/y position in my constructor so I don't think it can be that.

Comment: Nevermind I'm an idiot. Made a silly mistake on up in the code. Sorry.